# How to load an image and use it as vertex weight

Tags: customization, vertex-weights

Many times I have come accross this, would be possible to exchange vertex maps as images between different scenes, or even load animated ones to serve as weight maps ?
I have an intuition that either sverchok or AN would be capable for doing so.
Any advices or directions would be really appriciated, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

try to use this node
https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/blob/master/docs/nodes/generators_extended/image_components.rst
it allows to do vertex masking by coefficienting.

[image]

Comment: thank you @nikitron sverchok is apparently a great tool and I am using it often. Masking is a thing for sure, do you think that it would be possible to use vertex id and combine it with data from UVs in order to have weight map textures ? Does this make any sense for you ?

Comment: why not? just do it